# Is `方法是通过xxx` a correct sentence? i.e. 中文中,介宾结构能作为名词(宾语)使用吗

Tags: translation, grammar, sentence-structure, phrase

The phrase often appears in english-chinese translation.

For example:

> If you want to become a better photographer, the only way is through repetition. 
>   如果您想成为一名较好的摄影师，惟一的方法是通过反复练习。
>
> The third way is through free and conscious decision
>   
>   第三种方法就是通过自由、有意识的决定

The english version is correct, but I think the Chinese version is wrong grammatically. Because 通过xxx is a 介宾结构, 介宾结构 can't be used as 主语. I also don't think it can be used as 宾语.

For me, the tranlate version is acceptable, but I am not sure if it's correct. Still, I don't know how to search it quickly online, when I search it, I always find English grammar. Plz show me authoritative books or other resourses or common grammar rules not a simple yes or no.

In addition, If the answer is not, how to translate that.

Answer (score 2):

'through' implies 'going through' and  通过 is the correct translation for it. There's nothing wrong with the first sentence

When you 'going through' something to get somewhere, that something must have a length for you to go through (you have to spend a period of time)

- 通过反复练习  (through repetition) sounds right because 'repetition' requests a considerable length of time
- 通过自由、有意识的决定 (through free and conscious decision) doesn't sound right because 决定 (decision) happens in an instant.

The more reasonable sentence would be:

> The third way is **through** free and conscious **consideration**
>
> 第三种方法就是**通过**自由、有意识的**考虑**
>
> *通过考虑 (through consideration)*

or

> The third way is **to trust** free and conscious **decisions**
>
> 第三种方法就是**信赖**自由、有意识的**决定**
>
> *信赖一个决定 (trust a decision)*

Comment: 方法是一个名词，"通过xxx"能作为名词用吗

Comment: 通过 is a verb, 通过XXX is a verb phrase;  "方法就是通过XXX" = "the method is to go through (the procedure of) XXX"

Comment: 通过XXX的方法 = through the method of XXX; "通过XXX的" is an adjectival phrase for 方法

Comment: 通过here is prep.，介词短语为什么能作名词用

Comment: 通过 is used as a verb mostly, but in this context, you are right, it is preposition for the noun XXX and XXX here is  "自由、有意识的考虑" and 考虑 is a noun here

Answer (score 2):

就是 can be followed by any single word,noun,verb,adjective,adverb,etc. or a phrase,NP,VP,PP (preposition phrase) etc. in the present case 通过自由、有意识的决定 may be considered a PP, see examples for 就是 in online dictionaries, e.g. bkrs 就是(emphasizes that sth is precisely or exactly as stated)，examples for 就是  with typical preposition 在。。。：http://www.iciba.com/%E5%B0%B1%E6%98%AF%E5%9C%A8

re 通过
bkrs has 通过 II cov.
by (means/way of); through, "cov." google: A coverb is a word or prefix that resembles a verb or co-operates with a verb. In languages that have the serial verb construction, coverbs are a type of word that shares features of verbs and prepositions,

examples for 就是通过 
http://www.iciba.com/%E5%B0%B1%E6%98%AF%E9%80%9A%E8%BF%87
就是在

Comment: I don't think there are any diff between 就是 and 是 in grammar. In your latter examples, 通过xxx 是状语

Comment: example phrase 1: ...首要职责就是通过...,phrase 2:...方法就是通过... structure: NP就是通过。。。。seems to be same as above

Comment: 政府的首要职责(就)是(通过抑制通货膨胀来)保持货币稳定。 In my example, the sentence structure is different.